Initialization error when calling a function in an imported helper file
After writing a lot of TypeScript form logic held in multiple files, I thought I would include all my common functions in a helper.ts file.  Getting it wired up is proving a bit difficult. Be interested in hearing any advice.
I have set up simple project structure for an app. To start with I have 2 files

\utils\helper.ts
   // show a simple dialog
   export function displayPromptText(titleText : string, promptText : string)
   {
     let alertStrings = { confirmButtonLabel: "Ok", text:promptText, title: 
     titleText  };
     var confirmOptions = { height: 400, width: 450 }; 
     Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, confirmOptions).then(  
     function (success) {    

     console.log("Dialog closed using OK button.");
     }, function (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
   }  

 )   
}


\Forms\MyForm.ts
  import * as helper from  "../utils/helper"
  // also tried this
 // import { displayPromptText } from "../utils/helper";


  // if you call the line below say in Form load you get the intialisation error 
  helper.displayPromptText("test","test");




